# java webservice client

Tags: java, webservice-client

I have  stfw but I cannot find a simple / standalone  way to create a webservice client in java.

Does anyone have a link/sample into this?

Comment: @Matt, try asking Google about "stfw"....

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen....lmao...how ironic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [Axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/)?

Just follow the [quickstart guide](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_4_1/quickstartguide.html) and you should be on your way.

Here is another more descriptive [guide](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_0/userguide3.html#Writing_Web_Service_Clients_using_Code_Generation_with_Data_Binding_Support)

Comment: Is not Axis2 a webservice - "server"? ... I'll take a look at the quick start you sent. :)

Comment: No, Axis does both clients and server side webservice generation.
Remember to use the ANT wsdl2java task rather than messing about with the Wsdl2Java command line prompt :)

Answer (score 2):

[soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a great tool to test a Web Service. It is really simple to either create a server stub to test your client or just send client request to any Web Service.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most simple ways is to use apache cxf. There is a good documentation to create a client [here](http://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html). You will need java 5, not 1.4!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're referring to a SOAP web service? For a RESTful web service in which requests are submitted via HTTP GET, you really don't need anything more than a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AXIS WSDL2JAVA to generate the client stubs from the WSDL.

Also, you can program using the SAAJ.